# Turning On Arduino LED

Tags: c#, arduino

I am trying to get code on an Arduino to be contacted by my C# program, to turn on and off the onboard (pin 13) LED. This is the code that I have loaded into the Arduino:

```
void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}
void loop()
{
 if (Serial.available() > 0)
 {
  int b = Serial.read();
  if (b == 1)
  {
   digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  }
  else if (b == 0)
  {
   digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  }
  Serial.flush();
 }
}
```

I have found and downloaded [this code](http://stigern.net/blog/?p=349) and got the LED to work! (Hooray!)

I have tried to reverse engineer the code into my own, with a simple OnButton and OffButton, but it will not work. Can someone please take a look at the code below and tell me if I'm missing something obvious.

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Ports;

public static System.IO.Ports.SerialPort serialPort1;
private delegate void LineReceivedEvent(string line);

private void establishConnection()
{
   System.CompnentModel.IContainer components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
   serialPort1 = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(components);
   serialPort1.PortName = "COM7";
   serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
   serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;
   serialPort1.Open();
}
private void terminateConnection()
{
   serialPort1.Close();
}
private void OnButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   establishConnection();
   serialPort1.Write(new byte[] { Convert.ToByte("1") }, 0, 1);
   terminateConnection();
}
private void OffButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   establishConnection();
   serialPort1.Write(new byte[] {Convert.ToByte("0") }, 0, 1);
   terminateConnection();
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can see when I click the C# buttons that the Ardiuno is receiving some kind of command, and it works with the code that I downloaded in the link above... I'm pulling my hair out...

Comment: How many times are you actually establishing a connection that you aren't terminating?

Comment: Oops, forgot to type in the Terminate line there. I was testing having with out it.

Comment: I just added in the full code including terminateConnection();

Comment: ... so now are you aware that you've just poorly reimplemented a `using` statement?

Comment: Do I not need the System.IO; if I'm using System.IO.Ports ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: `SerialPort` implements `IDisposable`.  If you're going to establish a connection in the manner you're currently doing, you should not have a `serialPort1` class-level variable but instead change your code such that `using (var serialPort = EstablishConnection()) { ... }` will work.

Comment: Try with the connection already open. In other words, move establishConnection(); outside the button and terminateConnection(); in the form closing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Arduino code:**

```
void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}
void loop()
{
 if (Serial.available() > 0)
 {
  int b = Serial.read();
  if (b == 1)
  {
   digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  }
  else if (b == 0)
  {
   digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  }
  Serial.flush();
 }
}
```

**C# code:**

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Ports;

public static System.IO.Ports.SerialPort serialPort1;
private delegate void LineReceivedEvent(string line);

public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   System.CompnentModel.IContainer components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
   serialPort1 = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(components);
   serialPort1.PortName = "COM7";
   serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
   serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;
   serialPort1.Open();
}
private void OnButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   serialPort1.Write(new byte[] { Convert.ToByte("1") }, 0, 1);
}
private void OffButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   serialPort1.Write(new byte[] { Convert.ToByte("0") }, 0, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are several things you may want to consider.

- The First one is the [`serialEvent()`](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SerialEvent) function.

This function is called whenever data arrives to the corresponding serial port (for arduino Mega and Due there are other functions such as `serialEvent1()`, `serialEvent2()` and so forth...)

This would be the code for your arduino:

```
void serialEvent() {
  while (Serial.available()) {
    // get the new byte:
    char inChar = (char)Serial.read(); 
    if (inChar == '0')
      digitalWrite(13,LOW);
    else if(inChar == '1')
      digitalWrite(13,HIGH);        
  }
}
```

- The second one is Firmata Library

[Firmata Library](http://arduino.cc/en/reference/firmata) implements Firmata protocol for communicating with software on a host computer.

Arduino IDE comes with a firmata example, with this one you have everything setup to be able to communicate with your hardware through serial. this way you can deploy the firmata example to your arduino and configure everything (setting up `pinModes`, reading and writting values to digital and analog pins etc... ) from your `C#` Application